# Desktop pc wont turn on if plugged with SSHD drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, power-supply

I have been using Seagate 1TB desktop sshd over 2 years, it was working well until recently had an issue with my psu and had to replace it.After replacing the psu pc wont power up if the sshd is connected, without it system normally starts and ask for boot device.I have tried different power and sata ribbon/port,the cpu fan just flicks for half a second when I press start button.

Plugged a different hdd and system works fine.So I am thinking if its dead then the system should run and ask for a boot device.is the drive causing a short circuit? Is there any way to repair it or recover data ?

Comment: Did you try a different (internal) power cable?

Comment: yes , I have tried different internal power cable of the psu. with the other hdd both power cable works. also tried a dead hdd and pc powers up ask for boot deice.but the sshd wont let the pc power up

Comment: It sounds like this drive is what caused your issue with the previous PSU. Chances are that a power regulator on the drive is shorting to ground and causing your PSU to shut down. Repairing the drive is a job for specialists.

Answer (score 1):

## The hard drive electronics is defective

As you are thinking, there is probably short circuit on the SSHD board.

You have basically two options now:

1. Don't need the data on it:

   Throw it away and buy a new one.
2. Need the data on it:

   There are special data recovery services which require you to pay quite a lot of money to get your data back.

Comment: Or you could try to take the electronics from another same drive that has the same firmware revision.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That would require him to calibrate the board. I don't really understand electronics, but I tried this once, and did not work as simply as switching the boards. The repair shop told this to me then.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, someone also had kind of similar issue as mine [link](https://superuser.com/questions/906299/computer-wont-fire-up-more-than-one-second-with-hdd-connected) but I could not understand what solved is problem

Comment: @KamrulHaasan His problem was caused by wrong pinout of case's buttons/LEDs to the motherboard. I doubt, that you would have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the PC flicks for a moment, and then turns off again, and works without that one device, there are 3 possibilities:

- The PSU is at it's limit, the last connected device (especially mechanical harddisc with a high startup current) hits it's limit.
- The device shortens +5V or +12V. So the PSU detects the overcurrent and switches off.
- The connector you use shortens itself only when connected, because of physical damage.

I think you have to replace the hdd, as a repair is more expensive.

Comment: for the first possibility you mentioned , should I check with a different PSU if that works ?

Comment: Remove any other component you don't need for booting.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, although the system works with different hdd with same psu I will check with a different psu and removing components as you said